# python to oracle db connection making delay

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm using following code to connect to a remote oracle DB server, But it takes more than 10 second only to create the DB connectivity, then the DB SQL query return result instantly. Same connection made by the nodejs and it works perfectly. checked the connectivity between the source and destination, but cannot see any issue. Can you help me to diagnose this issue. I'm using;
python 3.6 and use oracle instant client libraries( basic) to connect

```
import cx_Oracle

dsn_tns=cx_Oracle.makedsn('dbhost','port',service_name='SERVICENAME')
conn = cx_oracle.connect(user=r'USER_NAME',password='******',dsn=dsn_tns)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""SIMPLE SELECT QUERY""")
for row in c;
    print (row[0],'-',row[1])
conn.close
```

Comment: Do an "strace python connect.py". Here you will see the syscalls.

Comment: Thanks for this , Now I can see the syscalls getting timed out in following location, need to dig more. "futex(0x56413124c9c8, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec+1671793111, tv_nsec=5000000}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY) = -1 ETIMEOUT (Connection timed out)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it may happen because of slow random number generation.

Take a look here https://learn.capstorm.com/copystorm/frequently-asked-questions/problems-solutions/how-do-i-fix-random-oracle-login-connection-timeouts/

Or here https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1594701.1

Comment: but then can it happen continuously?

Comment: Once you start using urandom, the solution should be stable.

Comment: Do you know how to use it with Python?

Comment: The easiest way is to rename /dev/random to /dev/random_org and then create a link to /dev/urandom called /dev/random. It will affect all the apps in the server though.